# Sinatra doesn't load assets

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a sinatra landing page. Server starts by execution `index.rb` in root folder.

For example:

```
  get '/en' do
    I18n.locale = 'en'
    erb :index, locals: {langswitch: "/ru", current_locale: "en"}
  end
```

renders `index.erb` and works well.

This page has:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
```

And if I open this link, it points to `http://0.0.0.0:9292/index.css`, retrieves css file and renders page as expected.

However, there is also

```
  get '/agreement/en' do
    I18n.locale = 'en'
    erb :agreement, locals: {langswitch: "/ru", current_locale: "en"}
  end
```

If I visit the same link from this page, it instead leads to `http://0.0.0.0:9292/agreement/bootstrap.css`, instead of `http://0.0.0.0:9292/index.css` and fails to retrieve file.

Same with all of my images, other css files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to put all your assets in public folder. Then you need to modifie 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">` 
to
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.css">`. 
So all you need to do is to put `/` before `index.css`